# Forbidden: / 403 error while sending image from react to django using axios

Tags: reactjs, django, rest, axios, imagefield

I have a reactjs project that makes requests using API to django-rest-framework. I am trying to create an image field in reactJS that sends image to django server on submitting. Maybe the error is with csrf token or maybe not. I am a newbie. Please help.
If possible please help me with the correct code. Thankyou veru much
**Image.js**

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';
    
    axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFTOKEN';
     axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    
    export default function Image() {
    const[images,setImages]=useState(null);
    
    function handleImages(e){
     
      setImages(e.target.files[0])
    }
    function handleSubmit(evemt){
    
      const formData= new FormData();
      formData.append('images',images)
      axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/',formData,{
       headers:{ "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }}
       ).then((res)=>{
         console.log(res)
       }
       )
    }
        
      return (
        <div>
          <input type="file" name="images"  accept="image/*"  onChange={handleImages}/>
          <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Upload</button>
        </div>
      )
    }
```

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework.parsers import FileUploadParser
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import RentDetailsSerializer
from  firstapp.models import RentDetails
from rest_framework.parsers import MultiPartParser, FormParser

class RentDetailsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class=RentDetailsSerializer
    queryset=RentDetails.objects.all();
   
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, FormParser]
```

**serializers.py**
from rest_framework import  serializers
from firstapp.models import RentDetails

```
class RentDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
      images=serializers.ImageField(required=False)
      class Meta:
        model = RentDetails

        fields = ['floor_no','distance','location','area','no_of_rooms','price','property_type','images']
```

**settings.py**

```
    REST_FRAMEWORK = {
           'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
               'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser'
           
           ]
       }
    # REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    #     'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    #         'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
            
    #     )
    # }
    
    
    # CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
    CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
        "accept",
        "accept-encoding",
        "authorization",
        "content-type",
        "dnt",
        "origin",
        "user-agent",
        "x-csrftoken",
        "x-requested-with",
    ]
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
     'http://localhost:3000',
     'http://localhost:8000',
]
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "XSRF-TOKEN"
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

Comment: `formData.append("image", images[0]);`....to get image in views ....`image = request.FILES.get('image')`

Comment: image field in api's views.py?

Comment: Is your backend running on AWS? Does it work when you run the backend locally?